Implementing App Tracking Transparency for Flutter
My Flutter app was rejected by Apple because of not implementing ATT.
What is your solution for App Tracking Transparency for Flutter apps? I researched on the Internet, I did not encounter an official guide or solution for this problem.
Apple Source:(But not Flutter)
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency?language=objc
Extra question:
My app does not use Admob or any other Ads. It uses some firebase libraries including
firebase_analytics: ^10.10.4

And also it uses Revenucat library.
Must I implement ATT for my iOS app according to Apple rules? I prefer implementing...(to guarantee) but this an extra question.
Thank you.

https://pub.dev/packages/app_tracking_transparency use this

https://pub.dev/packages/app_tracking_transparency
This package is working without a problem. Xcode:15.3, Flutter Version: 3.19.6, MBP 2020 M1.
